# How to define a class in another file in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have this in MyClass.js:

```
function MyClass(name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

module.exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

And I have this in Main.js:

```
var MyClass = require('./MyClass');

var obj = new MyClass('Something');

console.log(obj.Name);
```

But I'm getting the error `TypeError: Object is not a function` happening on the 'n' of new.

How can I define a class in another file in nodejs? I feel like this should have worked just fine, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said

```
module.exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

which means

```
var MyClass = require('./MyClass').MyClass; // MyClass attached to the exports
```

If you want it to be directly available on the require you'd need to do

```
module.exports = MyClass;
```